# Pasar parametros desde php a script en linux

Tags: php, linux

Estoy intentando pasar 3 parámetros desde php a un script en linux.El problema esta en que no consigo que se pasen todos los parámetros.

Este es mi codigo:

```
$asd=$name;
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
$raid=$checkbox[$i];

$asd=$asd ." ". $raid;

}
  $railvl1 = exec("sh /var/www/proyecto/borrarraid1.sh ".$asd);
```

$asd contiene esto: `string(15) "md2 sdc sdd "`

mi script es este:

```
mkdir $1
mkdir $2
mkdir $3
```

Me crea la primera carpeta bien, la segunda me la crea con el nombre sdc? y la 3 no la crea.
Cual puede ser el problema?
gracias

Comment: puedes ser mas claro como que traen los `checkbox` y que es valor tiene `$name` si quieres crear carpetas con php es solo con la funcion `mkdir()`